# Which compiler do I Use for iPhone App

Tags: iphone, compiler-construction, app-store

I am very new to iPhone app development.I haven't find good article about compiler usage in Xcode. Which compiler do I use for app compilation and what APP store will accept.

Comment: I am pretty sure there are tutorials for this...

Comment: could you please share the links

Answer (score 1):

The preferred method to build apps is using Apple's Xcode.  Older versions of Xcode used gcc.  The current version of Xcode supports either llvm or llvm-gcc.  Apple currently seems to allow the use of any compiler that emits legal static ARM code with calls to only Apple's public APIs (including one such tool from Adobe's Flash suite).

Answer (score 0):

Xcode uses the LLVM compiler. You do not need to worry about which compiler to use though. Simply install Xcode and develop your application in it. Xcode takes care of the compiling and other build steps for you.